# Help with retrieving answers from radio buttons

Tags: php

```
$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$pw = '';
$db = 'pmdb';

mysql_connect($host,$user,$pw); 
mysql_select_db($db);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Questions WHERE QuizID=1");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $array[] = $row;
}
for($i=0; $i<=($num_rows-1); $i++)
{
  $title = $array[$i]['Title'];
  $ans1 = $array[$i]['Answer1'];
  $ans2 = $array[$i]['Answer2'];
  $ans3 = $array[$i]['Answer3'];
  $ans4 = $array[$i]['Answer4'];
  echo $title.'<br>';
  echo '<form method="post">';
  echo '<input type="radio" name="ans'.$i.'">'.$ans1.'<br>';
  echo '<input type="radio" name="ans'.$i.'">'.$ans2.'<br>';
  echo '<input type="radio" name="ans'.$i.'">'.$ans3.'<br>';
  echo '<input type="radio" name="ans'.$i.'">'.$ans4.'<br>';
 }
echo '<input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit">';
echo '</form>';
```

I manage to display the question followed by the corresponding choices and at the bottom a submit button.

How would I, on click of the submit button, get the values that the user have chosen for each question that was looped out from the database? `ans1`, `ans2`, etc.

This is necessary to compare their answer to the answer key and compute their score.

.help please! Thank you very much and More power!

Comment: You're outputting a `<form>` tag for each question, which makes the HTML invalid. That should be done outside of the parent `for` loop.

Comment: .alright, I've corrected it.. what should be next?

Comment: You are closing `</form>` outside of the loop ... you have to close your `</form>` inside the `}` .. and apply action to it .. `<form method=post action=page.php>` ... or move out of the loop the first form tag `<form method....>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign a value to each of the radio inputs, the updated script could be:

```
$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$pw = '';
$db = 'pmdb';

mysql_connect($host,$user,$pw); 
mysql_select_db($db);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Questions WHERE QuizID=1");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $array[] = $row;
}

//Start the form
echo "<form method=\"post\" action=\"path/to/receiving.php\">\n";

for($i=0; $i<=($num_rows-1); $i++)
{
  //Render a question + the answer choices
  echo $array[$i]['Title']."<br />\n";
  for ($j=1;$j<=4;$j++) {
    echo "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"ans$i\" value=\"$j\">".
      $array[$i]['Answer'.$j]."<br />\n";
  }
}

//End the form
echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"submit\" id=\"submit\">\n</form>";
```

Now to read the values of the answers from within PHP:

```
  echo $_POST["ans1"]; 
  //The answer given for question 1, will be between 
  //  1-4 or null (if they didn't answer
```

Comment: @zerey: Find a basic tutorial online for processing `$_POST` data with PHP.